# Remove duplicate values from a listagg in oracle

Tags: oracle, replace, listagg

I have used `listagg` to concat and list books along with the supplementary books name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(LISTAGG(',-'||B1.BOOK_NO||','||B1.BOOK_NAME||','||A.AUTHOR_NAME||',-'||B2.BOOK_NO||','||B2.BOOK_NAME)   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B2.BOOK_NO),2) 
FROM BOOK_LIST B1
INNER JOIN AUTHORS A ON A.AUTHOR_NO=B1.AUTHOR_NO
INNER JOIN SUPPLEMENTARY B2 ON B2.BOOK_NO = B1.BOOK_SUP_NO
WHERE B1.SEQ = 123;
```

But since the number of supplementary books are more i get the main book name repeatedly.

Is there a way to remove the duplicate main book name and number.

My ouput is like this

`-99,Anders Carlson ,-109,John Stuart,-99,Anders Carlson ,-47,James Anderson`

Here the value 99 is repeated i want only one 99.

Desired Output:

`-99,Anders Carlson ,-109,John Stuart,-47,James Anderson`

DB data:

Book_list:

```
NO | MAIN_BOOK_NO | MAIN_BOOK_NAME | BOOK_SUP_NO | AUTHOR_NO
1  |    12        |    xyz         |   5         |   2
2  |    22        |    abc         |   7         |   4
```

Authors:

```
NO | AUTHOR_NO | AUTHOR_NAME
 1 |  2        | Alex
 2 |  3        | Leonard
 3 |  4        | Benjamin
```

Supplementary:

```
NO | BOOK_NO | BOOK_NAME 
1  |   5     |   ABC
2  |   5     |   XYZ
3  |   7     |   LMN
4  |   7     |   DEF
5  |   7     |   NEW
```

The output should be like

```
         NAME
12,xyz,Alex,-5,ABC,-5,XYZ
22,abc,Benjamin,-7,LMN,-7,DEF,-7,NEW
```

Similarly for the entire data in the table

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result.

Comment: @Aleksej i have added my output and desired result please check

Comment: If you have a book with many supplementaries, how to choose the one to show? Do you have an ordering, do you want a random one?

Comment: there is no order, I want to list the book and its supplementary books under a single column name

Comment: It's not clear to me. Please post some sample data (an extract of daa in your tables) and what you need to get for that data. Also, why do you need the AUTHORS table in your query?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to append the list of supplementary books to the main book, so you're actually after something like:

```
SELECT B1.MAIN_BOOK_NO||','||B1.MAIN_BOOK_NAME||',-'||
         LISTAGG(B2.BOOK_NO||','||B2.BOOK_NAME, ',-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B2.BOOK_NO) 
FROM   BOOK_LIST B1
       INNER JOIN AUTHORS A ON A.AUTHOR_NO=B1.AUTHOR_NO
       INNER JOIN SUPPLEMENTARY B2 ON B2.BOOK_NO = B1.BOOK_SUP_NO
WHERE  B1.SEQ = 123
GROUP BY B1.MAIN_BOOK_NO, B1.MAIN_BOOK_NAME;
```

Comment: I am getting a `not a single-group group function` error

Comment: is b1.seq the primary key for the book_list table?

Comment: Yeah its the primary key

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer to add in the missing group by clause. If you're running this for multiple rows in the book_list table, then you'll probably need to add `B1.SEQ` into the group by clause as well.

Comment: Yes, It will thow 'ORA-00937: not a single-group group function error

Comment: @pahariayogi that's not the most helpful comment in the world, given that the OP had already confirmed that the error was occurring. Plus, I've updated my answer already, so it shouldn't raise that error any more.

Comment: @pahariayogi it's not that you offended me, it's more that comments are for clarifying things or providing constructive criticism. Your earlier comment, whilst being true (at least, at the time you wrote it), didn't add anything of value. If you'd have added something along the lines of "you'll need to add a group by clause to the query in this answer", that would have been more helpful. Hopefully that clarifies things?

Comment: upvoted for simplicity of your SQL. I hope, it should help @Tony

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
select T1.MAIN_BOOK_NO, T11.MAIN_BOOK_NAME, LISTAGG(',-'||',-'||T1.BOOK_NO||','||T1.BOOK_NAME) WITHIN GROUP (order by T1.BOOK_NO)
from
(
SELECT B1.MAIN_BOOK_NO, B1.MAIN_BOOK_NAME, B2.BOOK_NO, B2.BOOK_NAME
FROM BOOK_LIST B1
INNER JOIN AUTHORS A ON A.AUTHOR_NO=B1.AUTHOR_NO
INNER JOIN SUPPLEMENTARY B2 ON B2.BOOK_NO = B1.BOOK_SUP_NO
WHERE B1.SEQ = 123
group by B1.MAIN_BOOK_NO, B1.MAIN_BOOK_NAME, B2.BOOK_NO, B2.BOOK_NAME
order by B2.BOOK_NO
) T1 
group by T1.MAIN_BOOK_NO, T1.MAIN_BOOK_NAME;
```